# UIText view not starting from the beginning

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

i have a UIText View on my ios app, and when i open the app, the text view text starts from the middle. How do i get the text to start from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Interface Builder, scroll down to the view section and change the mode from the default value of Scale to Fill to Top.

Answer (score 0):

check the frame of the UITextView, it seems like the "x" value is off from what you say

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your constraints? Most of the time, you will need 4 constraints to describe height, weight, x and y position. It sounds like you were missing the x constraint or there is an error in it's definition (Mostly a leading space constraint). If you just dropped the UITextView and hit run, you have to add the constraints by ctrl+dragging the uitextview to a reference position (e.g. the parent view):
[image]